# Discrete math 4 proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I have a few questions that i have answered but i am not sure if its proof enough, if you could help me out and tell me if i am correct or not thta would be great.

Question 1: For all sets A,B,C we always have A ⊆ B ⊆ C ∧ C × B ⊆ B × A ⇒ A = B = C. true or false?
**answer**: i said true and the proof: x $\in$ B × A and x $\in$ C × B for some a $\in$ A and b $\in$ B which gives us a $\in$ A $\subseteq$ B $\subseteq$ C => a $\in$ B and a $\in$ C also we get b $\in$ B $\subseteq$ C => b $\in$ C så we get x = (a,b) $\in$ C × B and x $\in$ B × A. is this proof enough or even correct?

Question 2: For all prime numbers, p, q, the following is true: p|q ⇒ p = q. true or false?
**answer**: i said true and the proof: if p divides q then it has to be p = q because ex if p = 2 and q = 2 then the statement holds otherwise if p = 2 and q = 3 then the p = q doesnt hold, so prime numbers can only be divided by themselves or by 1.

Question 3: For all integers, a, b, c, the following is true: ab|c ∧ bc|a ∧ ac|b ⇒ a = b = c. true or false?
**answer**: i said false and the proof: if a = -2 and b = 2 and c = 2 then ab|c ∧ bc|a ∧ ac|b holds but a = b = c does not hold

Question 4: There are graphs with in total 5 vertices. Further, each vertex is connected (with one edge) to an odd
number of other vertices but not to an even number of other vertices. true or false?
**answer**: i said false and the proof: it is impossible to draw that because if we have 5 vertices and every vertice is connected with an edge to an odd amount of other vertices and no even amount of vertices, which cant be true because the even vertices must connect to an even amount of vertices, all vertices cant be odd.

So these are my 4 proofs that i tried to prove, am i correct on them or can someone correct me if im wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1), there is a counterexample: $A$ and $B$ are empty sets, $C$ is an arbitrary non-empty set.

2) is definitely correct.

In 3), I am confused by your notation. Usually $a|b$ means that "$a$ divides $b$", that is, $b$ is divisible by $a$. If this is the case, then by multiplying them together we get $(abc)^2|abc$, which is equivalent to $|abc|=1$. A counterexample can be $(a,b,c)=(-1,1,1)$.

If you mean that $ab$ is divisible by $c$ and so on, then your example works. $(a,b,c)=(6,10,15)$ is another one in strictly positive numbers.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your answers aren't that rigorous, but depending on the class level that may not matter.  Remember unless you're doing proof by counterexample, examples are not proof.

2) If $p|q$, then $q=pn$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$

But p,q are both primes.  So for $n \ge 2$, $q=np$ implies q is composite, which would be a contradiction.

So $p=q$ since $n=1$ is the only possibility